# Has anyone used swaggervel in a full REST API?

Tags: laravel, swagger

I'm having a lot of trouble getting Swagger 2.x annotations to work in Laravel 5.3.

GET methods work fine, but I cannot find any online examples of how to construct POST/PUT annotations.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I have used Swagger   into a Laravel 5.2 projects ,it is a bit complicated but and the end everything worked Great. you can check this great application that will help you to create your swagger json .
[StopLight](https://stoplight.io/)

Thanks , good look with your API